Why NLL does not end mutable borrow in the middle of a match arm
Here is my code:
fn update(&mut self) -> bool {
    let now = std::time::Instant::now();
    let delta_time = now - self.last_update;
    self.last_update = now;

    match self.state {
        ClientState::MainMenu(ref mut menu) => {
            // TODO: handle menu transition and rendering
            true
        }
        ClientState::Playing(ref mut game) => {
            game.update(delta_time);
            self.render(game)
        }
        ClientState::PauseMenu(ref mut menu, ref mut game) => {
            // TODO: do not update/render game in SP mode while in the menu (full pause)
            game.update(delta_time);
            self.render(game)
            // TODO: handle menu transition and rendering
        }
    }
}

fn render(&self, game: &Game) -> bool {
    match self.renderer_to_surface.render(game) {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(wgpu::SurfaceError::Lost) => { 
            self.renderer_to_surface.reconfigure();
        }
        Err(_) => return false,
    }

    true
}

For information, game.update is a mutating method, that's why in match arms Playing and PauseMenu I need to access game as a mutable reference. But past calling this method, I don't need the mutable borrow anymore since self.render is a non-mutating method. However the compiler still complains at self.render(game) that self cannot be immutable borrowed because it's still borrowed mutably since ref mut game.
But NLL should be able to drop this mutable borrow before starting a new immutable borrow, since the mutable reference is not used anymore in the scope. Do you know why it won't do this?
Here is an exemple of the code that reproduces this error.
I know other questions are linked to NLL not dropping borrow when we think it should do, but the code case seems different here. There is no conditional lifetime of the mutable reference here. In all case in my function, the mutable reference game is not used past calling update or after the match clause.

A [mre] must be included within the question, not just linked to.

I don't think the duplicate is right; this is not due to "conditional control flow across functions" (polonius will still not allow this) - game was only acquired via mutable reference to self.state and even though game can be relaxed to an immutable reference after .update(), the mutable reference it was derived from is still held and thus it conflicts when you try to borrow self again. You will need to either use two matchs (one mutable, one not) or change render to not take self and use separate parameters instead.

@kmdreko Thank you much. I was also wondering how my problem was linked to the conditional control flow limitation of the NLL engine. I still don't understand why the reference to self cannot be relaxed to an immutable one too, since the reference to game could be. Is it normal limitation of the borrow checker ? It seems weird to me that I have to borrow self again to alleviate the problem, it looks very hacky.

"Is it normal limitation of the borrow checker?" - the behavior is intentional, if it were not like that then other patterns wouldn't work (you can get an unguarded reference to the contents of a Mutex if you have an exclusive reference to it - Mutex::get_mut - and if the original exclusive reference were relaxed when the nested mutex was relaxed then it could violate memory safety)

@kmdreko Is it not something the borrow checker could detect ? I mean, I find it problematic that my code is logically valid, but that an intentional limitation of the borrow checker that applies to other cases makes my code rejected by the compiler, even though it does not violate memory safety

The borrow checker does not guarantee that all conceptually valid uses are allowed - only that it disallows all invalid uses. Pointers can be used to do valid things that the borrow checker can't verify. Could this case be detected and allowed? Maybe, but that would at least be an exception to what I mentioned above and require more local analysis. Exceptions to the rules are best avoided and here there are reasonable workarounds (mentioned in my first comment).
